# dealing on convergent issue

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a_1=\frac{1}{2}$, $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{1-a_n}$ show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists. I know that this sequence converges, but I have no idea about how to prove it. How should I prove it?

Comment: How do you know it converges? What have you tried?

Comment: by drawing a graph of y=x and y=sqrt(1-x) and i observed how it moves.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my misunderstanding and inadequate replies to your question.

I only thought about the odd sequence.

Since it is trivial that $0 < a_n < 1$ for all positive integer n,
$$a_n^2 < a_n$$

Therefore, 
$$a_n+1 = {\sqrt {1-a_n}} < {\sqrt {1 - a_n^2}} = {\sqrt {a_{n-1}}}$$
(using $a_n^2 = 1 - a_{n-1}$)

So we can argue that 
$a_{n+1} < {\sqrt{a_{n-1}}}$ for all n > 2

From this recursive form, for positive integer n, 
$$a_{2n+1} < {\sqrt[2^n]{a_1}}$$

which shows that odd and even sequence both have upper bound,
and since it is easy to show $a_{2n+1}$ increases as n gets larger,
the sequence $a_{2n+1}$ converges.

I expect that similar method(idea) can be used to even sequence, $a_{2n}$.
But in that case, lower bound will have to be determined since $a_{2n}$ decreases.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence converges, then $\sqrt{1-a_n}$ must exist so $a_n \leq 1 \forall n$.  In addition, because $a_1=\frac{1}{2}$, $a_{n}$ is increasing until where $a_{n+1}=a_n$:
$$a_n=\sqrt{1-a_n}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$$

This is very brief, so see if you can expand on this idea.